# Spring Integration 4.1.0 Migration problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm having problems migrating my application form spring-integration 4.0.4 to the recent 4.1.0 release.

Once replacing the jars, my integration context throws an exception for each `<recipient-list-router/>` tag.

The thrown exception is a `java.lang.ClassCastException` the message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62 cannot be cast to org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport
    at org.springframework.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:130)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanReagistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 20 more
```

I am using Spring-Integration 4.1.0.RELEASE, spring-core 4.1.2.RELEASE, and running on jdk1.8.0_05.
My Integration beans context contains two `<recipient-list-router/>` tags, which upon removal, do not throw this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from `AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean` says:

```
else if(!(this.handler instanceof AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler)) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("adviceChain can only be set to AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler or its subclass, "
                    + ((IntegrationObjectSupport) this.handler).getComponentName() + " doesn't support it.");
                }
}
```

So, let's switch of `debug` for the `org.springframework.integration` category!

From other side I agree that it is a bug, because if our `messageHandler` is a `Proxy` we can't simply cast it to the `IntegrationObjectSupport`.

So, feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket on the matter.

From other side it isn't clear why removal of `<recipient-list-router/>` evict an issue...

Because `<recipient-list-router/>` doesn't support `<request-handler-advice-chain>`.

I agree that we have introduced in the 4.1 the `RecipientListRouterManagement` and if you use JMX the special MBean will be registered for the `RecipientListRouter` and the last one becomes `Proxy`, but it isn't clrear how that proxying relates to the `request-handler-advice-chain` log message...

Would be great if you can debug for that line from `AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean` and show us the real object for that `Proxy`.

And show, please, more StackTrace . Maybe we can see more context to figure out the root of cause.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that definitley seems to work.
Sorry for not posting more stacktrace, but the computer in question is not connected to anything (company policy) so it's a bit difficult...